# Fragment Manager error : An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

Im getting this error: An object reference is required for the non-static field, method or property 'Android.App.FragmentManager.BeginTransaction()' in the line :             FragmentTransaction transaction = FragmentManager.BeginTransaction();

```
void mEditar_Click (object sender, EventArgs e )
            {
                FragmentTransaction transaction = FragmentManager.BeginTransaction();

                dialog_Editar_produto dialog_editar = new dialog_Editar_produto ();
                dialog_editar.Show (transaction, "dialog fragment");

                dialog_editar.mOnEditarComplete += dialog_editar_mOnEditarComplete;

            }
```

What can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That error message indicates that BeginTransaction is not a static method of the FragmentManager class.
Try accessing the FragmentManager object in your class.

Try this:

```
FragmentTransaction transaction = this.FragmentManager.BeginTransaction();
```

Comment: now I get this:          cannot create an instance of the abstract class or interface 'Android.App.FragmentManager'

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager()
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
```

For more go to
http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html